# Incongruent Solutions Modulo $p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, congruences

> Let $p$ be an odd prime and $k$ a positive integer such that $\gcd(p,k)=1$. Show $x^2\equiv k \bmod p$ has zero or two incongruent solutions.

I think we are supposed to assume that $x$ is a solution, and that $y$ is also a solution where $y$ does not equal $x$. Then show $y \equiv -x \bmod p$

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: @NasuSama, please edit only a few old posts (months to years old) per day; the activity tends to fill up the front page with old, already answered posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\;a\;$ is a solution, then also $\;-a\;$ is, and

$$a=-a\pmod p\iff 2a=0\pmod p$$

But $\;p\neq 2\;$ and also $\;a\neq 0\pmod p\;$ , otherwise $\;a^2=0=k\pmod p\;$ , contradicting $\;(k,p)=1\;$ .

Comment: But how do you know that there aren't more solutions?

Comment: (I just want you to comment on that, your answer is otherwise perfectly fine.)

Comment: If you know that the set $\;\Bbb F_p\;$ of all residues modulo a prime under the usual operations of sum and multiplication modulo is a field, then it is easy: over a field a polynomial of degree $\;n\;$ has *at most* $\;n\;$ different roots, and this is what happens here with the polynomial $\;x^2-k\in\Bbb F_p[x]\;$ . Now, if you don't know this ,then perhaps we can go as follows: $$a^2=b^2\pmod p\iff (a-b)(a+b)=0\pmod p\implies a=b\;\;or\;\;a=-b $$ since there are no non-trivial zero divisors in the set of residues.